Sum of two iid RVs compared to single RV
Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be positive integer iid random variables with a distribution $P(X_i = x) = f(x)$
The distribution for the sum $Y=X_1 + X_2$ is given by:
$P(Y=y) = g(y) = \sum_{k=1}^{y-1} f(k)f(y-k)$
It seems intuitive that $g(x)/f(x)$ is an increasing function of $x$ (at least for large enough values of $x$). That is, large values are more (increasingly) likely from the sum of $X_1$ and $X_2$ than from either alone.
Is there a way to prove this (or show a counterexample)?
Update - comment below points to a counterexample when the domain of $f(x)$ is the odd numbers. What about the case where $f(x)$ is a decreasing function of $x$?

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ take only odd values, and have positive probability of any odd value. What can you say about $g(x)/f(x)$ for large odd $x$...?

Good point. I guess I'm interested in the class of probability distributions that are in some sense smooth, but not necessarily a standard form, though I'm not sure how to specify that precisely - I'll have to think if it can be...
